# Is there an alternative Drupal 7 module for the Advertisement module?

Tags: 7

We are looking to upgrade a site to from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 that uses the Advertisement module. There is an alternative module to the Advertisement module for D7?

Comment: I've been exploring the same issue. I was not impressed by openx. It looks that at this time (June 2011) that we're going to have to make a custom data type and go from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just released is the [SimpleAds](http://drupal.org/project/simpleads) module for Drupal 7. This module provides a way to feature advertisements on a Drupal website. It displays graphical ads in configurable blocks. It records and reports useful statistics. It is easy to configure and does not depend on other contrib modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [OpenX](http://drupal.org/project/openx).

> Show ads from a OpenX (formerly OpenAds) server. OpenX is a open source online program that will allow you to catalog and display advertisers, just like Google, Yahoo or Microsoft.